# Calcular diferencia de medias para datos agrupados por más de una variable y graficarlos en 3D

Tags: r

Tengo un código con el que represento una serie de datos utilizando la función `facet_wrap`. Aquí adjunto un ejemplo mínimo con unos datos ficticios. La representación es correcta, sin embargo, dada la gran catidad de niveles que en los datos reales incluyo en la variable cb, me gustaría probar con algún tipo de representación en 3D.

Mi objetivo es el siguiente:

1. Obtener, para cada nivel de `cb` y `x`, la diferencia entre las medias de `y` entre las condiciones `z`. Es decir, en pseudocódigo, la diferencia `mean(y) de L - mean(y) de M`, `mean(y) de L - mean(y) E` y  `mean(y) de M - mean(y) E`, agrupados por `cb` y `x`. Obtendríamos por lo tanto 3 nuevas columnas de datos (L-M, L-E, M-E).
2. Ahora que tendría las nuevas variables denominadas `L-M`, `L-E` y `M-E` (que representan las diferencias de las medias de `y`), desearía representar cada una de ellas en un gráfico en 3D. Un eje sería `x`, otro `cb` y otro `dif_y`. Las tres gráficas formarían una composición con facet_wrap.

Mis intentos hasta ahora han pasado por intentar generar un nuevo archivo csv con las nuevas columnas, y después intentar operar dentro de una nueva tubería. Pero el proceso es farragoso y me pregunto si no hay una manera facil de hacer esto directamente desde los datos originales que comparto.

Para el punto 2 estaba intentando utilizar la librería `rayshader`, pero si se recomienda otra aproximación soy todo oídos.

Gracias por los comentarios y ayuda por adelantado.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
tribble(    ~y,    ~cb,   ~z,    ~x,
            1     , 0,   "E"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "E"    ,1,
            1.2   , 0,   "E"    ,1,
            3     , 1,   "E"    ,1,
            1.5   , 0,   "L"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "L"    ,1,
            1     , 0,   "L"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "L"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "M"    ,1,
            3     , 1,   "M"    ,1,
            1.5   , 0,   "M"    ,1,
            2     , 1,   "M"    ,1,
            2     , 0,   "E"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "E"    ,2,
            3     , 0,   "E"    ,2,
            3     , 1,   "E"    ,2,
            0.5   , 0,   "M"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "M"    ,2,
            2     , 0,   "M"    ,2,
            2     , 1,   "M"    ,2,
            3     , 0,   "L"    ,2,
            1     , 0,   "L"    ,2,
            2     , 0,   "L"    ,2,
            1     , 1,   "L"    ,2)-> datos
datos %>%
  group_by(x, z, cb) %>%
  summarise(media = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),                            
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = media + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = media - (2*error_est)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = media, color = z)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = z), size=0.5) +                      
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,               
                    ymin = intervalo_inf),
                width=0.3) + 
  labs(x = "x", y = "y", color = "Condition") +
  scale_color_brewer(type='div', palette="Spectral") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,7, by=1)) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.text=element_text(size=12)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=14),
        axis.title=element_text(size=14))+
  facet_wrap(~cb)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para la primera parte de tu pregunta entiendo que lo que deseas es una manera rápida de obtener las diferencias en medias de los parámetros z

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
datos_p<-tribble(    ~y,    ~cb,   ~z,    ~x,
                  1     , 0,   "E"    ,1,
                  2     , 1,   "E"    ,1,
                  1.2   , 0,   "E"    ,1,
                  3     , 1,   "E"    ,1,
                  1.5   , 0,   "L"    ,1,
                  2     , 1,   "L"    ,1,
                  1     , 0,   "L"    ,1,
                  2     , 1,   "L"    ,1,
                  2     , 0,   "M"    ,1,
                  3     , 1,   "M"    ,1,
                  1.5   , 0,   "M"    ,1,
                  2     , 1,   "M"    ,1,
                  2     , 0,   "E"    ,2,
                  2     , 1,   "E"    ,2,
                  3     , 0,   "E"    ,2,
                  3     , 1,   "E"    ,2,
                  0.5   , 0,   "M"    ,2,
                  2     , 1,   "M"    ,2,
                  2     , 0,   "M"    ,2,
                  2     , 1,   "M"    ,2,
                  3     , 0,   "L"    ,2,
                  1     , 0,   "L"    ,2,
                  2     , 0,   "L"    ,2,
                  1     , 1,   "L"    ,2)
#Realizamos el cálculos de las diferencias de medias 
Resultado_restas<-datos_p %>%  group_by(x,cb,z) %>%
                               summarise(medias=mean(y)) %>%
                               pivot_wider(names_from = z,values_from = medias) %>%
                               mutate(L_M=L-M,L_E=L-E,M_E=M-E) %>%
                               select(x,cb,L_M,L_E,M_E) %>%
                               pivot_longer(c(-x,-cb),
                               names_to = "Diferencias",
                               values_to = "Resultados")

    # A tibble: 12 x 4
       # Groups:   x, cb [4]
   x    cb Diferencias Resultados
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>
 1     1     0 L_M             -0.5  
 2     1     0 L_E              0.150
 3     1     0 M_E              0.650
 4     1     1 L_M             -0.5  
 5     1     1 L_E             -0.5  
 6     1     1 M_E              0    
 7     2     0 L_M              0.75 
 8     2     0 L_E             -0.5  
 9     2     0 M_E             -1.25 
10     2     1 L_M             -1    
11     2     1 L_E             -1.5  
12     2     1 M_E             -0.5
```

Aquí terminamos la primera parte de la pregunta, lo siguiente es realizar la gráfica en 3D que mencionas y para esto utilizara la library de rayshader

```
library(ggplot2)
library(rayshader)

grafica_2d<-Resultado_restas %>% ggplot(aes(y=Resultados,x=cb,color=x)) +
                 geom_point()+
                 facet_wrap(vars(Diferencias))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego esta gráfica guardada en grafica_2d utilizando la función de la library plot_gg , generamos la grafica en 3D

```
plot_gg(grafica_2d, height=3, width=3.5, multicore=TRUE, pointcontract = 0.7, 
         soliddepth=-200)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]